# Is there a way to get back anonymous event handlers that were registered with Event.observe in Prototype?

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs

Interfacing with legacy code, and I've got something like this:

```
Event.observe(some_form, 'submit', [some anonymous function])
```

I'd like to grab that anonymous event handler back out, is there an easy way to do that in Prototype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the version of Prototype. From a more general answer [I wrote previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106):

- version 1.5.x:

  ```
  // inspect
  Event.observers.each(function(item) {
      if(item[0] == some_form && item[1] == 'submit') {
          alert(item[2]) // [some anonymous function]
      }
  })
  ```
- versions 1.6 to 1.6.0.3, inclusive (got very difficult here)

  ```
  // inspect. "_eventId" is for < 1.6.0.3 while 
  // "_prototypeEventID" was introduced in 1.6.0.3
  var submitEvents = Event.cache[some_form._eventId || (some_form._prototypeEventID || [])[0]].submit;
  submitEvents.each(function(wrapper){
      alert(wrapper.handler) // [some anonymous function]
  })
  ```
- [Current] version 1.6.1 (little better)

  ```
  // inspect
  var submitEvents = some_form.getStorage().get('prototype_event_registry').get('submit');
  submitEvents.each(function(wrapper){
      alert(wrapper.handler) // [some anonymous function]
  })
  ```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  Looks like we're using 1.6.0.3 but I'm getting that Event.cache is undefined =(

Comment: @gct: `Event.cache` is set by virtue of simply including 1.6.0.3: (http://prototypejs.org/assets/2008/9/29/prototype-1.6.0.3.js). My guess is the `submitEvents` variable is what is undefined. This can happen when there simply haven't been any `submit` handlers bound **with Prototype** (read: *not* including `onsubmit="..."`) *at the point you are checking*. Need to see more code to help further.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want access to the handler, no, there's no easy way. You can of course stopObserving all prototype initiated handlers for an event type, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't too many other listeners on `some_form` + `submit`-event or you control all others you could get at it with

```
var boundSubmitEvents = some_form.getStorage().get('prototype_event_registry').get('submit');
boundSubmitEvents.each(function(wrapper){
    //do with wrapper.handler whatever
})
```

btw. what do you mean with

> grab that anonymous event handler back
>   out