# Using prototype.js, how do I get the list of observers associated with an object?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm attempting to return a list of observers associated with a particular object using prototype.js 1.6.1.  I've googled my eyes out all day and am getting frustrated.  I've discovered two methods that used to work with older versions, but do not work with the latest version of the library.  These include:

- Event.oberservers (Worked with version 1.5)
- Event.cache (Worked with a minor build released a year or so ago)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422696/update-how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-prototype

Comment: Thank you very much!  Though you should have left an answer so I could have given you proper kudos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition the link CMS pointed me at, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655943/is-there-a-way-to-get-back-anonymous-event-handlers-that-were-registed-with-event) was also helpful.